# WPF - Default Button Disable Style When Foreground applied

Tags: wpf

Button is applied with a `Foreground` when it is enabled. If it is Set as Disabled, default Button's Disabled `Foreground` need to apply.

```
<Button Width="150"
        Height="50"
        Content="Test"
        Foreground="Red"
        IsEnabled="False" />
```

I have Triggers for this button like

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFADADAD"/>
</Trigger>
```

This `Foreground` is not applied when it is enabled.

Any idea on this?

Need like below,

[image]

[image]

Comment: how can it work when you have initially set "IsEnabled=False"

Comment: @Sankarann - As per your statement `This Foreground is not applied when it is enabled.`. I guess you mean to say disabled here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you set the properties locally the trigger will not be able to change the value due to [precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).

Move the Foreground and IsEnabled property into the style:

```
<StackPanel>
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFADADAD"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>
<Button Width="150" 
    Height="50"
    Content="Test">
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand the question properly, because those codes posted in question should work fine. Following is a working sample to produce a Button exactly as the captured image shows. I put the Style as resource in the Button's container control -StackPanel in this case- :

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFADADAD"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Width="150" 
        Height="50"
        Content="Test"
        IsEnabled="True">
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: @RohitVats Really? I tested the code, with another Button say Button2. Button2 will toggle the styled button's IsEnabled property, and the style work fine, showing Red text when IsEnabled = true and grey text when IsEnabled = false. Or I misunderstand what OP is actually after?

Comment: I guess he want's some other color apart from `gray` since gray is be default color for disable button. If it's the case then his code and your code are perfect.

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to change the color of a disabled button. Gray is the default color for `IsEnabled == false` and it is apparently hard-coded into the Button class.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit Button's default template you can find the following trigger inside control template.

```
  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="#FF838383"/>
            </Trigger>
```

This trigger set Foreground to the content presenter using TargetName. No template binding used here. It directly assigns value. So the values you set for Foreground in Style Triggers will not be applied. You can edit the control template to achieve your requirement. This limitation not only for Foreground, for Background and BorderBrush also have this.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is working for me:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
     <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="{StaticResource FlatButtonNavigation}">
          <Border Name="ButtonBorder" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5"  
               BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2">
               <ContentPresenter Name="MyContentPresenter"
                   HorizontalAlignment="center"
                   RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                   VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                   TextBlock.FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                   TextBlock.Foreground="{StaticResource LeftPanelFontColor}"
                   Margin="10"/>
           </Border>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
              <Setter TargetName="ButtonBorder" Property="Background"  Value="LightGray"/>
              <Setter TargetName="ButtonBorder" Property="BorderBrush"  Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
              <Setter TargetName="MyContentPresenter" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
           </Trigger>
     </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be worked using styles as mentioned in the other answers, but there is no need to go outside the button to define the style, you can define a style explicitly related to the particular button:

```
<Button Width="150" Height="50" Content="Test">
   <Button.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Button">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
         <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFADADAD"/>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Button.Style>
   </Button>
</StackPanel>
```