# XAML + Awesome: change style on trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, font-awesome

Looking solution to change awesome foreground property by trgger.
Awesome icon using on button and need I wnat to change foreground when button is disabled.
XAML:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="serverButtons" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="24" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="{foreground_of_ImageAwesome}"  Value="#404040"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="{foreground_of_ImageAwesome}"  Value="DarkGray"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="serverBtnIcon" TargetType="{x:Type fa:ImageAwesome}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#404040" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

....

```
            <StackPanel x:Name="panel1" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="bntAddServer" Style="{StaticResource serverButtons}" Margin="5,0,5,5" ToolTip="Add new server">
                    <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Plus" Style="{StaticResource serverBtnIcon}"></fa:ImageAwesome>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnEditServer" Style="{StaticResource serverButtons}" Margin="0,0,5,5" ToolTip="Edit selected server">
                    <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Pencil" Style="{StaticResource serverBtnIcon}"></fa:ImageAwesome>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnDuplicateServer" Style="{StaticResource serverButtons}" Margin="0,0,5,5" ToolTip="Duplicate selected server">
                    <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Copy" Style="{StaticResource serverBtnIcon}"></fa:ImageAwesome>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnUpServer" Style="{StaticResource serverButtons}" Margin="11,0,5,5" ToolTip="Shift up selected server" IsEnabled="False">
                    <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="ArrowUp" Style="{StaticResource serverBtnIcon}"></fa:ImageAwesome>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnDownServer" Style="{StaticResource serverButtons}" Margin="0,0,5,5" ToolTip="Shift down selected server">
                    <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="ArrowDown" Style="{StaticResource serverBtnIcon}"></fa:ImageAwesome>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnDeleteServer" Style="{StaticResource serverButtons}" Margin="10,0,0,5" ToolTip="Delete selected server">
                    <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Minus" Style="{StaticResource serverBtnIcon}"></fa:ImageAwesome>
                </Button>
```

Please help find solution how to change foreground awesome icon by button trigger....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to override its different state's color by overriding the key matching the color you want to change.

The problem in your code is that the trigger is placed on the parent but you set the color on the style below which will take precedence over the color provided on the style of the container. [Here is a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796465/wpf-default-button-disable-style-when-foreground-applied)
If I remember well you don't need to set the color on the content but the button is fine: it will be inherited to the content.

There are some other topics that want to achieve the same goal [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40655926/styling-controls-how-to-overwrite-the-styles-in-different-visualstates-point)
The documentation on MSDN provides an example of how to change the visual states of the button [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates)